# Завершение Activity - не выводятся сохраненные параметры в SharedPreferences

Tags: android

Ребята помогите разобраться. Моя первая программа тест.

Есть две активити: MainActivity и MainActivityTwo. Я перехожу
между ними так:

```
Intent gotoanotheractivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivityTwo.class);
startActivity(gotoanotheractivity);
```

И со второй в первую:

```
Intent gotoanotheractivity = new Intent(MainActivityTwo.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(gotoanotheractivity);
```

В MainActivityTwo я за 12 правильных вопросов даю пользователю бонус - звездочку. Сохраняю ее с помощью

SharedPreferences и в MainActivity(меню приложения) достаю из настроек вывожу ее.

MainActivity:

```
if(mySettings1.contains(Tobe_Bonus_Star1)) { // получение 1 бонусной звездочки

     image_tobe1.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_gold);
      image_tobe1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

 }
```

Все работает, но когда я вторую активити завершаю методом finish() то бонусы не выводятся.

Подскажите почему?

Comment: Наверное вы звёздочку выводите в onCreate, а он не вызывается при возвращении к предыдущей активити. Попробуйте код установки звёздочки в onResume перенести

Comment: Спасибо,ЮрийСПб. Все работает.

Comment: Я написал в ответ подробнее. Вы можете отметить его верным (галочка слева от тела ответа) и проголосовать за него (стрелочки также слева от тела ответа)

Answer (score 2):

Всё дело в том какие методы жизненного цикла будут вызваны при разных способах отображения активити. При запуске активити через интент, в общем случае, активити будет создана и будет вызван её метод `onCreate()`, в котором вы и показываете звёздочку.

В случае же, когда вы из второй активити на первую возвращаетесь через завершение второй методом `finish()` у вас не происходит создание первой активити, метод `onCreate()` не вызывается и вы не видите изменений на экране.

В вашем случае можно действовать по разному. Простейший способ: устанавливать всё что нужно в `onResume()`. Второй, более правильный - подписаться на изменения в `sharedPreferences` в активити и в его колбэке совершать необходимые действия